# What am I missing - Angular service in different file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

RAPRequestService.js

```
angular.module('RecruitmentAuthorisationProcessApp').factory('RAPRequestsService    ', function ($http) {
    console.log('RAPRequestsService.js loaded...')
    var RAPRequestsService = {};
    RAPRequestsService.getRAPRequests = function () {
        return $http.get('/RAPRequests/GetRAPRequestsJSON');
    };
    return RAPRequestsService;
});
```

RAPRequestsController.js

```
angular.module('RecruitmentAuthorisationProcessApp').controller('RAPRequestsCont    roller', ['$scope','RAPRequestService',function ($scope, RAPRequestService)     {
    $scope.getRAPRequests = function () {
        RAPRequestsService.getRAPRequests().success(function (rapRequests) {
            $scope.data = rapRequests;
            console.log($scope.data);
        }).error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load rap requests: ' + error.message;
            console.log($scope.status);
         });
    }
}]);
```

RecruitmentAuthorisationProcessApp.js

```
 var RecruitmentAuthorisationProcessApp =      angular.module('RecruitmentAuthorisationProcessApp', ['ngRoute']);
 RecruitmentAuthorisationProcessApp.factory('RAPRequestsService',      RAPRequestsService);
```

When I load my view and open the developer tools, I see the error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/nomod?p0=RecruitmentAuthorisationProcessApp
>   at angular:1
>   at angular:1
>   at t (angular:1)
>   at Object.module (angular:1)
>   at RecruitmentAuthorisationProcessApp:1

What is my implementation missing?

I have my script registered in the Bundle.Config and loaded on the _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: You most likely have a typo somewhere. Start with fixing that white space inside the controller name. It also seems like you're declaring the factory twice. Whats that line after the app declaration at the bottom?

Comment: Update: admittedly i had some typos (missing 's' in RAPRequestsController.js) i've fixed that now, also removed the second line in RecruitmentAuthorisationProcessApp.js but still ending up with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in how i was trying to register the service in BundleConfig.cs
I tried to do a .IncludeDirectory and angular didn't like that. Instead i've had to include the service individually using .Include(..specify file path).
I don't know why it's rejecting the .IncludeDirectory which seems cleaner, but will revisit this when time permits.
For anyone having a similar issue, reference this article: https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/02/22/bundling-and-minifying-an-angularjs-application-with-asp-net-mvc